# Using RegEx in XSLT

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I need to parse Visual Studio automatically generated XML documentation to create a report. I decided to use XSLT but I'm very new to it and need help.
Common template is:

```
<doc>
  <members>
    <member name="F:MyNamespace">
      <summary>Some text</summary>
    </member> 
  </members>
</doc>
```

I want to isolate members with name which begins on some word, for example, P:Interfaces.Core. I decided to use RegExp in select statement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/">
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <body style="font-family:Tahoma">
                <p>Interfaces list:</p>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="doc/members/member">
                        <xsl:sort order="ascending" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="fn:matches(., 'P\..+')" />
                        <br />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why does I'm getting error:

> Namespace http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions does not contain any functions >

Where am I wrong? I found such code in examples, including w3c.org!

Comment: Abatishchev, see my answer. Of all the answers at this time only this one provides you with the exact XPath expression to use. It also discusses other available options, demonstrates the use of other available XPath 1.0 functions and how to implement ends-with() as XPath 1.0 expression. Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In case you're performing the transformation with Visual Studio X**, where X is not greater than 2008, this would be processed by an [**XSLT 1.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) processor (.NET's [**`XslCompiledTransform`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) or [**`XslTransform`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx)). XSLT 1.0 uses [**XPath 1.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath), not [**XPath 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) and its [**F & O**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) (Functions and Operations), which only became a W3 Recommendation last year.

**You have two options**:

1. *Use a compliant XSLT 2.0 processor*. If you prefer to stay within the .NET platform, then a suitable choice is [**Saxon.NET**](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)
2. *Just use the XPath 1.0 function* [**`starts-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions), which is sufficient to solve the current problem. 
   The expression: `starts-with(., 'P:Interfaces')` is evaluated to `true()` if the string value of the context node starts with the string 'P:Interfaces' and to `false()` otherwise.

Another Xpath 1.0 function that may come handy for such type of processing is the function [**`contains()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions).

Xpath's 2.0 function [**`ends-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) can be emulated in XPath 1.0 in the following way:

`ends-with(s1, s2)` ====`substring`(s1,`string-length`(s1)-`string-length`(s2)+1)=s2

where "`===`" means is "equivalent to".

Here we also used the XPath 1.0 functions [**`substring()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions) and [**`string-length()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions).

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer!
I already done something like you're talking about - I mean XPath 1.0, I use exactly what you said - starts-with(@name, 'T:MyNamespaces.Interfaces') and contains().

Answer (score 2):

If you are working exclusively in MS XML you can add custom functions written in a .net language of your choice. See the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx) (they use JScript). Then you could use regexes.

However, you should be able to use the [starts-with](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/index.html) xslt function to do what you need.

Comment: MS' implementation of XSLT doesn't support 2.0 functions.  You have to use an external XSLT library like Saxon.  More info here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94047/are-net-35-xpath-classes-and-methods-xslt-20-compatible

Answer (score 0):

These functions are from XPath 2.0 in XSLT 2.0.  .NET XSLT is at 1.0 and your xsl namespace reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

There is however an outofjail.get() with .net: there's always the possibility of passing a task to an [Extension Object](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=64).

Not good practice since it's an extension to XSLT, but sometimes you have to go with what works.