# URL and the & ampersand

Tags: url, xslt, escaping

Using XSLT and XPath 1.0, I have a string I want to escape for use on a URL, for example:

```
<description>one word &amp; another</description>
```

So, the text() of the description element should get URL escaped.

How would I do this?

Using C# (XslCompiledTransform) the code would be:

```
string a = Server.UrlEncode("one word & another");
```

And would produce:

```
one+word+%26+another
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your adjusted code makes an invalid assumption.  If you have the &amp; in your XML, and you parse it with an XML reader, you will never see &amp; in your strings in memory.  The XML parser will automatically convert it to the unescaped version.  So unless the string in your UrlEncode snippet is being ripped out of the XML using regex or something (which you should never ever do), its not applicable

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. How would you go about getting that output from XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built in to do this, but rather than reinvent the wheel there are style sheets already out there e.g.:

http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/url-encode/

The transforms are straightforward but (hopefully) someone else will have done the debugging for you...

Comment: So there's really no way to convert any short piece of text into a link, easily?

Comment: Not using XSLT alone - it's a generic transformation language, so it's not suprising really. You could start mixing in other technologies to simplify the task, for example you could manipulate the source XML (codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx) by using Server.UrlEncode after picking out the nodes from an XmlDocument with xpath and then push the result through XSLT. Depends on the context really.

Comment: Thank you, those style sheets have helped enormously.

Answer (score 2):

In XML (and therefore XSL) you need to escape the &, > and < using

```
&amp;
&lt;
&gt;
```

Comment: +1, although you generally do not *need* to escape `>`. http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax

Comment: True as this might be, this is watering down people's perception. It's simpler (and better, probably) to remember that `>` is not an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 2):

The fragment `<description>one word & another</description>` resembles XML, but the naked ampersand is illegal.  XSL requires legal XML.

One way to make it legal without substituting `&amp;` is to make the text into a CDATA section:

```
<description><![CDATA[one word & another]]></description>
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. I have adjusted my code snippet to compensate. Do you have an answer to my question, which is actually about how to replace the URL-illegal characters with valid ones ie to URL-escape the text?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use XSLT 2.0? I only mention it because there is a nifty URL encoding function which would sort out all your problems..

```
<xsl:value-of select="url:encode('This is URL encoded')" />
```

Comment: I would like to use XSLT 2, but I'm not sure which implementation to use for .NET

Comment: Maybe this will point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94047/are-net-3-5-xpath-classes-and-methods-xslt-2-0-compatible

Answer (score 1):

For my purposes, none of these solutions worked.  I was working within a proprietary framework, and using the entity:

```
&#38;
```

Was the only way I was able to append additional parameters to a URI string, in the context of an XSL template.